# How to locally Test Map and Reduce Code?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

If I have a map.py file that reads from multiple csv files and produces key-value pairs, how do I pass these to my reducer.py and test locally?

Comment: Install hadoop in pseudo mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using hadoop streaming, then you can test your scripts locally like this:

```
cat *.csv | map.py | sort -k1,1 | reducer.py
```

To pass data from mapper to reducer in hadoop-streaming, simply write `"<key>\t<value>"` to stdout

Comment: That's what I settled for. But instead used sort -n